# OpenLayers sencha 2 not redrawing entire map on active item change (Chrome on Android issue)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers 2.12/Sencha 2.4 app. On selecting a feature I wish to change to another view - a FormPanel. This works fine using Ext.View.setActiveItem(viewname).

However, there is an issue with Google Chrome on Android, when I change the view from the FormPanel back to the map view, and only after both the virtual keyboard and an Ext.Msg.alert() call have been invoked in the FormPanel.

I've analysed this with Chrome's debugger. When the I click on one of the form fields in the FormPanel, most of the OpenLayers tiles are removed from the DOM. When I set the active item back to the map view, no new tiles are added to the map div so the app ceases to be useful. The svg that is the vector layer also ceases to function usefully.

One version of the app is here: https://treemapp.se/fiddles/sencha/ol-sencha-4.html - all the code is in the html file.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Mini

Comment: Can you please show some code here where you think the problem lies?

Comment: Hi, see answer - mini

Answer (score 0):

I added map.updateSize() to the 'painted' listener, which has mostly solved the problem:

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {
        container1 = new Ext.Container({
            scroll: false,
            monitorResize: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component', //xtype: 'panel' - shows nothing
                id: 'map',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                listeners: {
                    painted: function(){
                        console.log( "painted" );
                        if( !map ) {
                            init( this.id );
                        } else {
                            map.updateSize();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Looks like I might need to add a layer.redraw() or layer.refresh() loop for all the layers, as one or two tiles don't get redrawn after the call to map.updateSize() - they do however get drawn after zooming or moving.

Mini

Comment: I didn't get the problem as well as solution here. Inside the listener, you are using 'map'. Nowhere in your code i can see it is defined.

Comment: Hey Anand - you can see all the code at the link I posted in the question.